# Getting an error while giving input to Conv1D layer in a Keras model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, tf-idf

I am using tf-idf vector data as an input for my Keras model. tf-idf vectors has the following shape:

```
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> (25000, 310617)
```

Code:

```
inputs = Input((X_train.shape[1],))
convnet1=Conv1D(128,3,padding='same',activation='relu')(inputs)
```

Error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_25: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

When I am converting the input to `Input(None,X_train.shape[1],)` then I am getting an error while fitting because the input dimension has been changed to 3.

Comment: Did the answer resolve your issue? If yes, then kindly accept it.

Comment: No, it didn't. I have figured out how to pass input. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then, could you please share your solution as an answer so others who have the same problem could benefit from it? And I am curious to know who it was resolved, as well. Thanks.

Comment: X_train = np.reshape(X_train, X_train.shape + (1,))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, X_test.shape + (1,))

Comment: Are you sure my solution did not work for you? `X_train = np.reshape(X_train, X_train.shape + (1,))` is the same as `X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))` if `X_train` is initially a 2D array as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work.

Comment: I think it's not working because here X_train is a csr sparse matrix.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the error (i.e. `expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`), `Conv1D` takes a 3D array as input. So if you would like to feed this array to it you first need to reshape it:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
```

And also set the input layer shape accordingly:

```
inputs = Input(X_train.shape[1:])
```

---

However, `Conv1D` is usually used for processing sequences (like sequence of words in a sentence) or temporal data (like timeseries of weather temperature). And that's exactly why it takes inputs with shape of `(num_samples, num_timesteps or sequence_len, num_features)`. Applying it on a tf-idf representation, which does not have any sequential order, may not be efficient that much. Instead, I suggest you to use a `Dense` layer. Or alternatively, instead of using tf-idf you can also feed the raw data (i.e. texts or sentences) directly into an [`Embedding`](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) layer and use `Conv1D` or `LSTM` layer(s) after it.